# How to: Reset Bootstrap button state after returning a file from the controller

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button that when clicked, executes an export of a file, and can be a lengthy process on the server, so I would like to put the button into the "loading" state.

However, since the controller returns a file, there button never "resets" and goes back to the normal state. I need some sort of javascript event where I can call the reset.

### Javascript

```
 $(".load-spin").on('click', function () {
      var btn = $(this).closest("ul").prev();
      $(btn).button("loading");
 });
```

### HTML

```
 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Book Actions <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
 @if (item.Published)
 {
      <li><a href="@Url.Action("Manage", new { id = item.BookId })">Manage/Edit</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="confirmDelete(@item.BookId)">Delete</a></li>
      <li><a class="load-spin" href="@Url.Action("Duplicate", new { id = item.BookId })">Duplicate</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a class="load-spin" href="@Url.Action("Export", new { id = item.BookId })">Export Configuration</a></li>
      <li><a class="load-spin" href="@Url.Action("Download", new { id = item.BookId })">Download (for offline use)</a></li>
 }
 </ul>
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult Export(int id)
 {
      // omitted for brevity
      return File(fullFileName, "application/zip", fileName);
 }
```

**What sort of event or action should I be listening for in order to call $(btn).button("reset")?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than add the action in the url, add an onclick event and then handle it with a function that sends an action to the controller that has a response where you can read the response and act accordingly.

Comment: You're saying to send it as an AJAX request instead? I thought you couldn't return files through ajax?

Comment: you can return files in ajax, i have returned PDFs plenty of times